# ANDROID: .java file became an XML

Tags: android

Please help me with this weird problem my 2 java files became an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.ROUNDED, com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.CUT}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable int getShadowCompatibilityMode()">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_DEFAULT, com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_NEVER, com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_ALWAYS}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable void setShadowCompatibilityMode(int) 0">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_DEFAULT, com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_NEVER, com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_ALWAYS}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.CompatibilityShadowMode">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_DEFAULT, com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_NEVER, com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_ALWAYS}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeUtils com.google.android.material.shape.CornerTreatment createCornerTreatment(int, int) 0">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.ROUNDED, com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.CUT}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearanceModel void setAllCorners(int, int) 0">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.ROUNDED, com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.CUT}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearanceModel void setBottomLeftCorner(int, int) 0">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.ROUNDED, com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.CUT}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearanceModel void setBottomRightCorner(int, int) 0">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.ROUNDED, com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.CUT}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearanceModel void setTopLeftCorner(int, int) 0">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.ROUNDED, com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.CUT}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
  <item name="com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearanceModel void setTopRightCorner(int, int) 0">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.IntDef">
      <val name="value" val="{com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.ROUNDED, com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily.CUT}" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
</root>
```

it is my first time encountering this

at first only 1 java file became like this then suddenly after i repeatedly rebuild my project another java file became like this. I don't know where to start in order to fix this

Comment: did your computer shutdown unexpectedly?

Comment: @faiizii no its not